# Text not wrapping in paragraph element

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have two floated divs, side by side, with p tags inside. The text within the p tags does not wrap and just overflows the container, as you can see in the text under the images:

[image: Example:]

My HTML looks like so:

```
        <div class="submenu">
            <h3>Destinations in Europe</h3>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">dfgdgdgfgdg</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">dfgdgdgfgdg</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">dfgdgdgfgdg</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">dfgdgdgfgdg</a></li>
            </ul>
            <h3>Features</h3>
            <div>
                <img src="/assets/images/o/menu/city-feat-one.jpg" />
                <h4>blahblah</h4>
                <p>
                    khkhjhjkhkyhkighkjfkhkiyhohhjkhjlhkluoiulohlhjhiououhljhiououhljhiououhljhiououhljhiououhljhiououhl
                </p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="/assets/images/o/menu/city-feat-two.jpg" />
                <h4>blahblah</h4>
                <p>
                    khkhjhjkhkyhkighkjfkhkiyhohhjkhjlhkluoiulohlhjhiououhl
                </p>
            </div>           
        </div>
```

My CSS:

```
#rb-menu-com li .submenu > div { 
    width:48%;
    float:left;
    position: relative;
}

#rb-menu-com li .submenu div p {
    color:#fff;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    position: relative;
}

#rb-menu-com li .submenu div img {
    border:1px solid #fff;
}
```

Has anyone experienced this before? I haven't!! Driving me mad!

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Word wrapping only occurs when there is a word break.

If you have a "word" that is as long as that, then there is no place for it to break.

The proper solution is to write real content and not nonsense strings of characters. If you are using user generated content, then add a check for exceptionally long words and disallow them (or cut out part of them for URLs while keeping the whole thing in a link).

Alternatively, you can use the [`word-break` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) to tell the browser to line break in the middle of words.

```
p { word-break: break-all }
```

(Note [browser support](https://caniuse.com/word-break)).

Alternatively, you can use `overflow` to truncate the text if it won't fit in the container.

Comment: thank you so much! I've been struggling to find what's causing the content overflow on my site. It's indeed related to word break!

Answer (score 147):

Give this style to the `<p>` tag.

```css
p {
    word-break: break-all;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Comment: This will break the individual words on their characters. You might want to use `word-break: normal;` and give the parent a `width`.

Comment: @MaraisRossouw This is the same one, that got accepted above.

Comment: white-space is what makes the difference here.

Comment: `white-space: normal;` fixed it for me

Comment: What does `white-space: normal` do? What is the default value?

Comment: @preciousbetine `white-space: normal` is the default behaviour that breaks when a space is encountered but doesn't break for hyphens and non breaking spaces. This article gives you a demo of everything: [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)...

Comment: So, the css `white-space` property does not have a default value then?

Comment: @preciousbetine `white-space: normal` is the default value.

Comment: If `white-space: normal` is the default value, then why do I have to manually set it before it assumes that value?

Comment: @preciousbetine The case here is there's some other CSS getting applied. That's why. Like using `* {white-space: nowrap;}` or something like this. Just to make things sure.

Answer (score 23):

**To anyone still struggling**, be sure to check and see if you've set a line-height value on the font in question: it could be overriding the word wrap.

Comment: Thank you for helping me narrow down this issue!  I could not get an absolutely positioned paragraph to wrap at all until I saw your answer.  Sure enough the font line-height had been set on a parent element and was getting in the way of any other attempt to affect the word wrap.

Answer (score 5):

That is because you have continuous text, means single long word without space. To break it add `word-break: break-all;`

```
.submenu div p {
    color:#fff;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    position: relative; 
    word-break: break-all; 
    background:red;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/v5TEE/)**

Answer (score 4):

This is not an answer to the question but as I found this page while looking to an answer to a problem that I had, I want to mention the solution that I found as it cost me a lot of time. In the hope this will be useful to others:

The problem was that text in a <p> tag would not fold in the div. Eventually, I opened the inspector and noticed a 'no breaking space entity' between all the words. My editor, vi, was just showing normal blank spaces (some invisible chr, I don't know what) but I had copied pasted the text from a PDF document. The solution was to copy a blank space from within vi and replace it with a blank space. ie. 
:%s/ / /g where the blank to be replaced was copied from the offending text. Problem solved.

Answer (score 4):

This is a little late for this question but others might benefit.
I had a similar problem but had an added requirement for the text to correctly wrap in all device sizes. So in my case this worked. Need to setup the view port.

```
 .p
   {
   white-space: normal;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    width: 96vw;
   }
```

Answer (score 4):

If the desired result is to break the line by complete word use:

```css
p { word-break: break-word; }
```

else you can use:

```css
p { word-break: break-all; }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use word-wrap to break words or a continuous string of characters if it doesn't fit on a line in a container.

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

this will keep breaking lines at appropriate break points unless a single string of characters doesn't fit on a line, in that case it will break.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7U2ga/)

Answer (score 3):

The solutions is in fact

```
p{
    white-space:normal;
}
```

You can change the break behaviors by modifying, word-break property

```
p{
    word-break: break-all; // will break at end of line 
}
```

break-all: Will break the string at the very end, breaking at the last word
word-break: is more of pretty brake, will break nicely for example at ? point
normal: same as word-break

Comment: `white-space:normal` is the default for `p` elements, so that won't make a difference.

Comment: `word-break: break-all` has already been suggested by four prior answers.

Comment: I tested this on live, may be will share screenshots

Comment: I was debugging a modified `p` value, thus, `white-space:normal;` was exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

EASY

```
p{
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. @Kevin Oonk's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22047878/51242) from 2014 already suggests `word-wrap: break-word;`. Please ensure your answer provides something substantive and new, and doesn't consist only of repeat information from existing answers.

Answer (score 0):

For others that find themselves here, the css I was looking for was

```
overflow-wrap: break-word;
```

Which will only break a word if it needs to (the length of the single word is greater than the width of the p), unlike `word-break: break-all` which can break the last word of every line.

[overflow-wrap demo](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/overflow-wrap/)

Comment: This did the trick, thank you very much! I had some long urls not wrapping but didn't want to cut off every single work.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `width: 100%;` to the offending p element solved the problem for me. I don't know why it works.

Answer (score -3):

add float: left property to the image.

```
#rb-menu-com li .submenu div img {
    border:1px solid #fff;
    float:left;
}
```