# How do I stop text inside element p from overflowing the viewport?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, web-developer-toolbar

[image]
[image]
I am using angular uib-accordion to display the details parsed from JSON in angularJS.

However after styling I have noticed that the paragraph text is overflowing the viewport on small resolutions.

The overflow is being caused by  `<p>{{position.shortDescription}}</p>`

---

[image]

### [image]

### THE HTML

```
<div class="row" ng-show="showMeDetails">
  <uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="position in departments.positions">
      <uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
        <uib-accordion-group>
          <uib-accordion-heading>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <div class="job-view">
                <h4>{{position.name}}</h4>
                <p>{{position.shortDescription}}</p>
              </div>


            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <div class="apply-btn">
                <button ng-click="applyAction($event,position.name)" class="btn btn-info" type="button">APPLY</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </uib-accordion-heading>
          <div class="position-full-description"></div>
          <div class="position-full-description" ng-repeat="description in position.fullDescription">
            <h4>{{description.headline}}</h4>
            <ul ng-if="description.type == 'list'" class="detailed_lines">
              <li ng-repeat="line in description.lines">{{line}}</li>
            </ul>
            <p ng-if="description.type == 'paragraph'" ng-repeat="line in description.lines">{{line}}</p>
          </div>
        </uib-accordion-group>
      </uib-accordion>
    </div>
  </uib-accordion>
</div>
```

---

### THE CSS

```
.job-view {
    display: flex;
    -webkit-display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    -webkit-align-content: space-between;
    align-content: space-between;
    padding-left: 50px;
    text-align: left;

}
```

---

### Full CSS

```
.navbar-nav {
    float: right;
}
.container-fluid .nav > li > a {
    color: #333a3f;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.container-fluid .nav > li > a:focus, .nav > li:active > a {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,rgba(0,179,255,0) 0%,rgba(0,179,255,0) 75%,#00b3ff 75%,#00b3ff 80%,rgba(0,179,255,0) 80%,rgba(0,179,255,0) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,rgba(0,179,255,0) 0%,rgba(0,179,255,0) 75%,#00b3ff 75%,#00b3ff 78%,rgba(0,179,255,0) 78%,rgba(0,179,255,0) 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,rgba(0,179,255,0) 0%,rgba(0,179,255,0) 75%,#00b3ff 75%,#00b3ff 78%,rgba(0,179,255,0) 78%,rgba(0,179,255,0) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,rgba(0,179,255,0) 0%,rgba(0,179,255,0) 75%,#00b3ff 75%,#00b3ff 78%,rgba(0,179,255,0) 78%,rgba(0,179,255,0) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top,rgba(0,179,255,0) 0%,rgba(0,179,255,0) 75%,#00b3ff 75%,#00b3ff 78%,rgba(0,179,255,0) 78%,rgba(0,179,255,0) 100%);
}
.nav > li > a:hover {
    background: none;
}
.btn-info {
    border-radius: initial;
    background-color: #32b5e5;
    padding: 5px 30px;
    border: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400px;
    font-color: #fff;
}
.btn-info:disabled {
    background-color: #5b9ec0;
}
.btn-info:active {
    background-color: #32b5e5;
}
.panel-heading {
    background-color: transparent;
}
.panel-default > .panel-heading {
    background-color: transparent;
}
.panel, .panel-group .panel-heading+.panel-collapse>.panel-body {
    border: none;
}
.jobs-space {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: auto;

}
.job-view {
    display: flex;
    -webkit-display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    -webkit-align-content: space-between;
    align-content: space-between;
    padding-left: 50px;
    text-align: left;

}
.job-description {
    display: block;
}
.custom-content-tabs[vertical="false"] > ul.nav {
    padding-bottom: 1%;
    padding-top: 1%;
}
.position-full-description {
    margin-top: 50px;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    text-align: left;

}
.position-full-description > .ng-binding {
    display: inline-flex;
    -webkit-display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding-left: 50px;

}
h4.ng-binding:before {
    white-space: pre;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
}
.detailed_lines {
    padding-left: 100px;
}
h5 {
    text-align: center;
}
.position-full-description > .ng-binding {
    font-style: italic;

}
p.ng-binding {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: black;
    font-weight: 500;

}
@media only screen and (max-width:1000px) {
    h4.ng-binding {
        white-space: pre;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: left;
        color: black;
    }
}

.container-fluid .nav > li > a {
    padding: 20px;
}
.carousel-row {
    height: 60px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
.carousel-dept {
    padding: 10vw;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
input[type=text], input[type=email], input[type=text], textarea[type=text] {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.btn-info {
    border-radius: initial;
    background-color: #32b5e5;
    padding: 5px 30px;
    border: none;
}
.btn-info:disabled {
    background-color: #5b9ec0;
}
.btn-info:active {
    background-color: #32b5e5;
}
.upload {
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
input[type=text] {
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
#unified-inputs.input-group {
    width: 100%;
}
#unified-inputs.input-group input:last-of-type {
    border-left: 0;
}
.btn-submit {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 40px;
}
textarea:focus, input[type="text"]:focus, input[type="password"]:focus, input[type="datetime"]:focus, input[type="datetime-local"]:focus, input[type="date"]:focus, input[type="month"]:focus, input[type="time"]:focus, input[type="week"]:focus, input[type="number"]:focus, input[type="email"]:focus, input[type="url"]:focus, input[type="search"]:focus, input[type="tel"]:focus, input[type="color"]:focus, .uneditable-input:focus {
    border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.075) inset,0 0 8px rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
    outline: 0 none;
}
.contact-form {
    margin-right: 1vw;
}
.add-icon {
    position: absolute;
    left: 95%;
}
.sub-form {
    display: inline-block;
    left: 10%;
}
```

Comment: Could you reproduce the problem with jsFiddle so that we can help you understand?

Comment: [Take a look at this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14477156/text-not-wrapping-in-p-tag) Take a look at this link, maybe the problem is solved

Answer (score 2):

Since it is under `job-view`  class try this on your css

```
.job-view { width : 100%; }
.job-view p { display : block; overflow-wrap: break-word; max-width : 100%;}
```

If you also need to apply on your list then also add below code to your css

```
 .job-view ul li {display : block; overflow-wrap: break-word; max-width : 100%;}
```

Comment: Not working, I tried all these previously. Even I did width:100vw on parent elements.

Comment: This was kinda hard to guest since we can't see the actual code and the complete css, might be some rules that overrides the condition. Try the updated code above, I added a display block on p and sets a max-width, If I remember there are bugs like this when the parent is set to flex

Answer (score 0):

add width:100% to p tag and use word-break: break-word or word-break-break-all

Comment: Tried with no luck.

Answer (score -1):

```
.job-view p{
white-space : pre;
}
```

Tried the above code which works perfectly.