# Text is overlapping it's P tag

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have some text within `<p>` tags, but the text isn't wrapping appropriately so is exceeding the width of the parent `<div>`.

Not sure if I'm missing something really obvious as never encountered this before, but have recreated it in the snippet.

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}

h4 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #0e2753;
}

.btn--vehicle-condition {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col 12 col-md-6">
      <div class="btn btn--vehicle-condition">
        <h4>
          Preowned
        </h4>
        <p>
          A bit of information about what 'Preowned' means and how it affects the buyer.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col 12 col-md-6">
      <div class="btn btn--vehicle-condition">
        <h4>
          New
        </h4>
        <p>
          A bit of information about what 'New' means and how it affects the buyer.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

I've looked at a few other similar posts, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14477156/text-not-wrapping-in-p-tag), but in their case it seems to be because there aren't any spaces in the text, which isn't the case here.

Comment: you have it inside the btn class which is white-space:nowrap, you could add an override: `.btn p {white-space:normal}` - little tip right click and inspect element, you can see all the styles affecting your element

Comment: Ah great, that was it - thanks!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/asimshahiddIT/gpna5fyv/3/

Answer (score 0):

you need to add css 
 .btn p {white-space:normal}

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/asimshahiddIT/gpna5fyv/3/`
```